# DevOps (Azure) Repo Configuration

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

**Very recently** our department switched from TFS to DevOps Azure using GIT.  We are all noobs as it relates to GIT.

Currently have several programs that are similar, called importers.  My first instinct is to put all said importers into a Rep.  After I did that, I only wanted to pull down one importer for an enhancement.  Once I did a pull from the Repo, I of course got ALL the importers and not just the **one** I needed.

In short, should every independent program be in its own Repo?  Is there a straight forward way in GIT to organize similar code bases? ( Folder structure or some other mechanism?? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on your preferences actually.
The best way would be to create a folder for each application (which you probably already did) and just clone the whole repository.

That works but you'll still get all your importers.
The only ways to separate those would be to :

- Create a repository for each importer
- Create a branch for each importer

The branch system is not the best one since it defeats the compartmentalizing advantage of these.
How is getting all the apps (considering they're in their separate folders) an issue ?

And to go further, the "even" better way would be to get a specific repository per application, create a "common" nuget package if code sharing is required because apps are similar and get these repositories in a projet (importers ?).

EDIT : I suggest you take a good look at branching strategies which might be a hassle at first but will surely increase your efficiency in the long run.

EDIT2 :

- GitFlow : http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
- Anti-GitFlow : https://barro.github.io/2016/02/a-succesful-git-branching-model-considered-harmful/
- OneFlow : http://endoflineblog.com/oneflow-a-git-branching-model-and-workflow

Comment: Sure :
GitFlow : http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
Anti-GitFlow : https://barro.github.io/2016/02/a-succesful-git-branching-model-considered-harmful/
OneFlow : http://endoflineblog.com/oneflow-a-git-branching-model-and-workflow

GitFlow being the most used I think, this is the one I personally recommend.

Comment: You could but once again, having a specific repository for each would be a better practice IMHO.